# Nuget remote feed hosting two folders?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-server

I have created an Internal remote feed using the below link.
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

I am using the local feed as of now, Using folders for different nupkg types and adding each folder as a nuget source.
I was wondering if we could get the folder option in the remote feed.

As of now all the packages go into one packages path, Can I have multiple package paths hosted by the same feed? Or should I create different feeds for each package path that I am planning to have?

I would like my nuget packages to be a bit more organised with similar package id ones in separate folders

Comment: You should probably investigate using a private repository such as Inedo's [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget), which gives you these sorts of options. [Disclaimer - my day job is at Inedo]

Comment: i have faced same problem. Is any other option to have access on multiple folder repository based on routing url.